# What command should I type to run Chrome from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I have remote box accessed by `VNC` and `jwm` desktop.
No menus, not desktop icons, only a terminal window.

I have downloaded Chrome's ***.deb*** package and installed it.

**How can I run it from the terminal window?**

Comment: You might be interested in this generalised question: [How can I know which commands were installed with a package?](http://askubuntu.com/q/234702/2355)

Comment: What do you mean what command should you run? If you're vnc'd in, just call the command by the name. If you don't know the name you can always run `x-www-browser` and it'll run the default browser.

Answer (score 148):

Well simply typing `google-chrome` works fine for me. It might not work if you installed Chromium. `chromium-browser` is for Chromium.

- For Chrome:

  ```
  google-chrome
  ```
- For Chromium:

  ```
  chromium-browser
  ```

However if it's a remote box... At least via ssh you must use `-X` when option connecting to be able to run windowed apps. Like this:

```
ssh -X username@server.lt
```

Comment: google-chrome-stable may also be the command.

Comment: chromium is command in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: `google-chrome-unstable` if you have download an unstable version such as Dev or Canary

Answer (score 22):

**If you get the path where the application is installed then you can run the application from there**

For example to know the path where `google-chrome` is located run this command:

```
whereis google-chrome
```

You will get the path like:

```
google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/bin/X11/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1
```

Now you can run chrome by either executing two commands:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
/usr/bin/X11/google-chrome
```

**Note:** it will be applied for all installed applications. Also, It would be possible that you would not get the path `/usr/bin/X11` or would get something different.

Hope you like this way to find the path and run chrome :)

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 15.10 this command works very well

```
google-chrome www.google.com
```

for more options you can use

```
google-chrome --help
```

Answer (score 3):

Type

```
google-chrome-stable
```

I use this command and it works for me. I too installed it using the .deb package. So this should work for you too. Typing an url after the command opens the url.

Answer (score 2):

Enter to open`google-chrome`, and `exit google-chrome` to close the Chrome browser