# How can I know which commands were installed with a package?

Tags: apt

How can I get a list of commands that have been installed with a particular package?

For example, if I install Chromium, what should type now? Or if I install `moreutils`, how do I know which commands have been installed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Short answer:

```
dpkg -L packagename | grep 'bin/'
```

## Long answer:

To get a list of all files installed in a package (say `moreutils`), run this command:

```
dpkg -L moreutils
```

Now, all we need to do is filter out the ones that are executable files in the path. In general, commands are installed to `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`, so we can simply match those patterns:

```
dpkg -L moreutils | grep -e '^/bin/' -e '^/sbin/' -e '^/usr/bin/' -e '^/usr/sbin/'
```

If you want something that's easier to memorise, but not completely accurate, just filter out lines with `bin/` instead:

```
$ dpkg -L moreutils | grep 'bin/'
/usr/bin/isutf8
/usr/bin/pee
/usr/bin/errno
/usr/bin/vidir
/usr/bin/zrun
/usr/bin/lckdo
/usr/bin/ifne
/usr/bin/mispipe
/usr/bin/parallel
/usr/bin/sponge
/usr/bin/ts
/usr/bin/ifdata
/usr/bin/vipe
/usr/bin/chronic
/usr/bin/combine
```

So, in this example, I have discovered these commands: `isutf8`, `pee`, `errno`, etc.

---

Some packages don't install commands into the path, but do install an icon for the GUI app. If you want to find the command that launches the application, you will need to find the installed `.desktop` file, and look at the line beginning with `Exec=`. For example:

```
$ dpkg -L worldofgoo | grep '\.desktop$'
/usr/share/applications/WorldOfGoo.desktop

$ grep '^Exec=' /usr/share/applications/WorldOfGoo.desktop 
Exec=/opt/WorldOfGoo/WorldOfGoo
```

So in this example, I have discovered that I should run `/opt/WorldOfGoo/WorldOfGoo` to launch World Of Goo from the terminal.

Comment: The `grep` part can be consolidated slightly based on the idea that all patterns end with `bin/`. (And I was unable to resist to trim the path names.) `dpkg -L moreutils | grep -e '/[s]*bin/' | sed -r 's/.*bin\/(.*)$/\1/'`

Comment: @lgarzo, you may have learnt this in the last 6 years but you can dispense with the grep and just `dpkg -L chromium-browser | sed -rn 's/.*bin\/(.*)$/\1/p'` as the `-n` and `p` cause only the altered lines to be printed. Saving you 60/1000ths of a second!