# How can I tell which package an executable came from?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm answering a question with a suggestion to use `rename`, and I realize I don't know what package it comes from (as part of the answer, I imagine saying something like "if you don't have `rename`, it's installed as part of [package]").

`man rename` tells me to `SEE ALSO: mv(1), perl(1)` - so my first thought is that it was installed with perl.

A related answer, [how to tell what was installed as part of a package](https://askubuntu.com/a/234703/23949), helps me figure out that the perl package includes `prename` but not `rename` - and it turns out that my `/usr/bin/rename` points to `/etc/alternatives/rename` which points to `/usr/bin/prename`

So this is still kind of confusing.  Did `/etc/alternatives/rename` point somewhere else before I installed perl?  Is there a general way to tell which package something comes from?

Comment: Of course, all these answers only relate to software installed as part of a (proper) package - if it was compiled from source or is actually made up of scripts installed by a custom installer you're stuck.

Comment: JFTR the opposite (executable from package) [would be this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937550).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/10997/find-what-package-a-file-belongs-to-in-ubuntu-debian

Answer (score 39, accepted):

install apt-file

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

update apt-file

```
$ sudo apt-file update
```

search the package a file belongs to

```
$ apt-file search filename
```

find path of executable

```
$ whereis rename
rename: /usr/bin/rename.ul /usr/bin/rename /usr/bin/X11/rename.ul /usr/bin/X11/rename     /usr/share/man/man1/rename.1.gz /usr/share/man/man2/rename.2.gz
```

search package

```
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/rename
ladr4-apps: /usr/bin/renamer
util-linux: /usr/bin/rename.ul
```

the package name is: `util-linux`

Answer (score 23):

Turns out `dpkg-query` is good to get information about installed packages, and with the -S [pattern] option will search for packages with files corresponding to [pattern].

```
dpkg-query -S [filename-search-pattern]
```

Comment: Simply `dpkg -S [binary-name]` works for me (on Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 5):

As of 2018

```
apt search filename
```

works for recent Ubuntu and most Debian based distros.

**Update May 2018:** Apparently no longer working with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Really? In Ubuntu bionic, this doesn't seem to search for filenames.  `$ apt search` yields nothing, vs `wajig which-package /bin/date` which says `coreutils: /bin/date`

Answer (score 3):

You can try `apt-file` (it's not part of default installation).

0) Update apt-file database

`sudo apt-file update`

1) Find binary

```
$ which rename
/usr/bin/rename
```

2) Find the package

```
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/rename
util-linux: /usr/bin/rename.ul
```

And voila -- rename is part of `util-linux`

Comment: Poor man's apt-file: `dpkg -S rename| grep -F $(which rename)`